# Why am I getting Kivy Errors when running even working code?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm getting errors running a `Kivy` app that I'm building.  I can copy and paste code from a tutorial and it will still fail in similar ways... I'm about to say "to hell with it", but I really want to learn to code and build apps.

Here's a sample of code:

```
import kivy
from collections import UserList
from configparser import ConfigParser
from kivy.app import App
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
import kivy.properties as kyprops
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.storage.jsonstore import JsonStore
from os.path import join
import requests

kv = Builder.load_file("main.kv")

class MainpageWindow(App):
    pass

class SingnupWindow(MDApp):
    pass

class LoginWindow(MDApp):
    pass

class MainApp(App):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.title = "Menieres Tracker"

    def build(self):
        Builder.load_file("kv")
        return MainApp

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Here's my current error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "c:\Users\Mickey\Desktop\Coding\Kivy Projects\Kivy Meniere's App.py", line 17, in <module>
     kv = Builder.load_file("main.kv")
   File "C:\Users\Mickey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 306, in load_file
     return self.load_string(data, **kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\Mickey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 408, in load_string
     self._apply_rule(
   File "C:\Users\Mickey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 621, in _apply_rule
     cls = Factory_get(cname)
   File "C:\Users\Mickey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\factory.py", line 146, in __getattr__
     raise FactoryException('Unknown class <%s>' % name)
 kivy.factory.FactoryException: Unknown class <SingnupWindow>
```

I've had multiple issues since installing Python — I had to drop back to a previous build (3.9.6) as 3.9.7 was totally not working.

Any help would be much appreciated, or I'm just going to quit.

Comment: The error is coming from your `kv` file. Please post that file.

Comment: Something odd going on there. You code loads a file named `kv`, and a file named `main.kv`. Post them both. By the way, 'main.kv` will get loaded automatically because of its name. Will likely cause problems by getting loaded twice.

Comment: Site is giving me problems trying to add my kv file.  Working on it.

Comment: in kivy we use one `App` or `MDApp` class in the all app

Comment: The code you posted has several issues. Please try to star with a simple tutorial so you can sort errors more easily. The beginners tutorial from Kivy is a good option: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/tutorials/pong.html

Comment: Thanks folks but honestly I can copy and paste code from a YouTube tutorial where I can see the output and mine will error when theirs passes.  Have uninstalled and reinstalled everything so many times I'm weary from it.  I have changed my code posted so many times that I can't remember what the original was.  I really am at a loss as to what's wrong.

Comment: In the python code `SingnupWindow` inherits from `MDApp`, which is not a widget class and so isn't recognised in the kv. Perhaps you meant to inherit from something else?